Architecture of an LSTM with multiple (dependent?) time series
If you have multiple time series data for a given problem (e.g predicting house prices and data is available per city).
Per city there is a list of features and the target feature.
If you want to train one LSTM of all the cities together, how you would approach that?
I was thinking of using a stateless LSTM architecture where I organize my input in such a way that each batch represent a time series of a city. If that approach would work, are there more things I need to account for?
What about making additional features with distance to other cities, thoughts on that?
